# How to get RecordEditForm Object Id

Tags: lightning-recordeditform

I have an Aura component and Im trying to retrieve the selected account id of this record edit form:

```
<lightning:recordEditForm objectApiName="Order">
    <lightning:inputField aura:id="input_field" fieldName="AccountId" required="true" onchange="{!c.handleAccountSubmit}"/>                      
</lightning:recordEditForm>
```

[image]
is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The change event passes back an array of ids, so it looks something like this:

```
   ({
        handleAccountSubmit: function (cmp, event, helper) {
        var tempsessionid = event.getParams().value;
        if (tempsessionid) {
            console.log(tempsessionid[0]);
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: thanks for the reply but ive tried to edit that to match aura's syntax and had no success

Comment: Can you post the handler code so other folks can take a look?

Comment: tanks for you question, but the handler is not really important here
I just want to use the record id of the selected value to insert an object 
so the way you are going to use to retrieve it doesnt really matter too much, you see?

Comment: The updated answer works for me

Comment: yeah, this answer now is what I wanted, thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

It should be available as the value attribute in the input field component. In this case you could do.

```js
var accountId = component.find('input_field').get('v.value')
```

Or you can bind the value attribute too:

```html
<lightning:recordEditForm objectApiName="Order">
    <lightning:inputField 
        aura:id="input_field" 
        fieldName="AccountId" 
        required="true" 
        value="{!v.accountId}"
    />                      
</lightning:recordEditForm>
```